# php mail() function and hotmail configuration in php.ini file

Tags: php, forms, email, configuration, hotmail

First of all I have a form on my page where the visitor can type their infos and then I want that forms info to be sent to the page's owners mail account when visitor is pressing "submit".

To be able to send the info to the owners email I thought of using mail() function in php. And for that I have changed in php.ini file to my hotmail account like this:
(I'm using misshosting as host)
php.ini:

```
   smtp_server=smtp-mail.outlook.com;
smtp_port=587;
auth_username= mickedance@hotmail.com
auth_password=****
allow_url_fopen = Off
allow_url_include = Off
asp_tags = Off
display_errors = Off
enable_dl = Off
file_uploads = On
max_execution_time = 30
max_input_time = 60
max_input_vars = 1000
memory_limit = 256M
session.save_path = ""
upload_max_filesize = 128M
```

And my mail.php looks like this(only testing to send email, not using any data from a form)

```
<?php
    echo "GOLD";
    if( mail("mickedance@hotmail.com","test from the bet", "Message")){
      echo "Mail Sent Successfully". date("h:i:sa");
    }else{
      echo "Mail Not Sent". date("h:i:sa");
    }
?>
```

It does echo out: "Mail Sent Successfully", but there's no mail either sent or recieved from my hotmail account.

Any thoughts how to send mail with mail-function and a hotmail account?

Comment: Did you check Spam folder in your hotmail account?

Comment: which os? mail on linux uses sendmail, not smtp.

Comment: Try to add a headers part to the mail function, with the 'From' header.

Code:

 `<?php
  $to ='user@hotmail.com';
  $subject = 'Mail subject';
  $message = 'Some message';
  $headers = 'From: user@hotmail.com';
  mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);
 ?>`

Comment: The mail was n spam folder, thanks for that. But however I wonder why I can't see the mail sent from php in my hotmail sent-folder? Is the mail not send through hotmail acvount even though I have those in smptp setting?